# GitHub Copilot in IntelliJ does not work, becomes red, cannot update it or uninstall it

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, github-copilot

My GitHub Copilot got messed up: it doesn't work and I cannot update it or uninstall it because I get an error.

When I type even one character in the IDEe the logo becomes red:

[image: when i type even one charcter in the ide the logo becomes red]

If I dare to try uninstalling it or update it I get this error:

[image]

I would appreciate an advice on how to make it work again. It is so darn convenient.

Comment: Delete it directly from the location mentioned in the error?

Comment: How about deinstalling IntelliJ and installing the plugin after a fresh installation?

Answer (score 2):

The copilot-agent-win.exe process does not stop automatically. Stop that process manually in Task Manager while the IDE is running. Then uninstall or update the GitHub Copilot. Restart the IDE and you should be able to use Copilot again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, though I already wrote the solution, in the end what I have done is

> delete it directly from the location mentioned in the error

I was able to delete it after I understood that `copilot-agent-win.exe` process does not stop automatically and i stopped it via the task manager.
Then I downloaded copilot again, and all is well now.